# AS3 3D-Renders slowly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d

Good time.

As you know,3d shapes in as3 are flat surfaces and we can make polyhedrons by moving and rotating that flat surfaces in the three dimensions.

**BUT**......

what about Non-Polyhedra shapes(spheres,cylinders)??

One way is to make surfaces using flat shapes.

An example to make a cylinder; you can copy this code to see what happens:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;




const angle:Number=Math.PI/180;

var numOfSides:uint=200;
  //number of sides around

var pixWidth:uint=4;
  //width and height of sides

var cldHeight:uint=20;
  //height of cylinder

var s:Sprite=new Sprite();

s.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff*Math.random());
s.graphics.drawRect(0,0,pixWidth,pixWidth);

addChild(s);

this.cacheAsBitmap=true;


  for(var n:uint=1;n<cldHeight;n++){
     for(var i:uint=1;i<numOfSides;i++){
         var prevS:Sprite=s;
         s=new Sprite();

         s.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff*Math.random());
         s.graphics.drawRect(0,0,pixWidth,pixWidth);

         s.x=   prevS.x +       Math.cos(-prevS.rotationY*angle)*s.width;
         s.y=n*pixWidth;
         s.z=prevS.z+Math.sin(-prevS.rotationY*angle)*s.width;

         s.rotationY=-i*(360/numOfSides);
         s.cacheAsBitmap=true;

         addChild(s);
      }
    s=new Sprite();
}
```

and my problems:

**Flash now renders EXTREMELY slow** :-(
please improve this code or suggest a better one.

Answer (score 0):

A few minor notes on the code:

1. Don't forget to end the fill when you're done(e.g. `s.graphics.endFill()` after the `drawRect()` call)
2. `cacheAsBitmap` works well for display objects without rotation applied if I can remember
3. 4000 (200*20) Sprites with 3D transformations applied might push the display list a bit.
4. Remember to also [sort the sprites](http://www.leebrimelow.com/flash-player-10-z-sorting-class/)

I recommend checking out these resources:

- [Flash & Math blog Icosahedron 3D tutorial](http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/cs4simple3d/icosa.html)
- [Senocular's exhaustive FP10 Drawing API article](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/flash10drawingapi/) (using drawTriangles() would be more efficient since you'll have a single Sprite on the display list)
- If you want to draw the vertices, it should be pretty fast to draw the [3D points projected to 2D on a bitmap](http://wonderfl.net/c/9ug3)

All of the above use Flash Player 10's features, but it might be much simpler to use a 3D API like [Away3D](http://away3d.com/) which already provides easy ways to draw cylinders (with textures) at very high speeds(especially newer versions that use hardware acceleration)

Comment: Away 3d and its sames are actionscript classes so there should be a way for me to do that without them.

Comment: of course, you're free to implement as you like, from scratch. If you want to implement this without software acceleration, I recommend using drawTriangles(), but it may still be slow drawing ~4000 faces. If you want to implement a hardware accelerated version from scratch, you can start getting into [AGAL](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=2555) (which Away3D handles for you)